# VSCode: Is there a way to switch between different settings fast?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started using Visual Studio Code.

I was wondering if there is a way to switch between settings using a hotkey.

For example let's say it's dark outside and I want to switch my theme. (I know there are day/night switcher extensions, but the ones I could find where only able to switch styles, and not other settings).

Is there some way to e.g. bind a command to swap out settings with different values? Or is there maybe an extension (that I didn't find)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the extension [toggle settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.toggle) and an article explaining more at [how to toggle settings in vscode](https://medium.com/hack-visual-studio-code/toggle-any-setting-in-vs-code-using-keyboard-shortcut-arguments-cdb5ddc56955).

Another extension: [settings-cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler).

Comment: Wow I didn't find these. Thank you so much! Went with settings-cycler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Setting Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JrgMeier.setting-switcher).
It lets you define multiple groups of settings. The settings can be switched via Status bar.